# Does anyone know what brand of dog toy this yellow, miniature, plush, duck toy is?

Tags: dogs, toys

My puppy uses this duck as a comfort toy. I have tried reverse image searching for this toy with no luck. I cannot remember where I purchased it, and I already cut off the tags. I'm looking for this exact toy. Has anyone seen this toy before and know where I can purchase it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: where are you located and how old is the toy,lots of petshops and vets do sell simmilar toys.i have seen a very simmilar toy in shops selling baby stuff so you might try there.

Comment: New York. The toy is no older than 4 months.

Comment: This question started a thread on meta [Product identification should it be allowed?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/product-identification-should-it-be-allowed) of the two answers given, both suggest this question is not a good fit for pets.se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toy was a Simply Fido product! Thanks, Instagram!